# Import formatting from Excel and apply to a pandas dataframe for export to excel

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

The formatting I'm creating is essentially a thin border on all cells and then a thick border for each 10x10 grid (it's for a cross-stitch pattern that I create in python).

I know how to apply openpyxl formatting to a pandas dataframe from scratch every time. It works fine, it's just slow because some of my patterns are large (90x370 or 240x240). This is because I'm iterating through rows and columns to apply the lines.

I think that it would be much faster if I could somehow import an excel file that's pre-formatted, add the data for the pattern (that's generated in python), then export with both the data and the formatting. I've been googling around and have just not even found the question asked (most questions are how to format using openpyxl, which I'm already doing).

Is there a way to do this with openpyxl? Another package? Or do I just need to stick with the time-intensive from-scratch formatting I currently have?

Comment: Why not use a template with the formatting already complete?

Comment: I did try that as well and the formatting wasn't retained once I added the pandas data

Comment: Are you pasting both formats and data? If so then you will overwrite the formats.

Comment: wb = load_workbook('C:/Templates/Grid.xlsx')
pattern.to_excel(wb, sheet_name='Pattern', header=False, index=False)
wb.save()

Comment: also, the load_workbook is an import of openpyxl (from openpyxl import load_workbook)

Comment: Going via Pandas will make this slow as it doesn't retain formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I found it here!

https://discuss.dizzycoding.com/copy-pandas-dataframe-to-excel-using-openpyxl/

from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows
rows = dataframe_to_rows(df)

for r_idx, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
for c_idx, value in enumerate(row, 1):
ws.cell(row=r_idx, column=c_idx, value=value)

Comment: This **is** covered by the openpyxl documentation: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/pandas.html